# After deleting an item from WPF Listbox and changing selected index, highlight style is different until actual mouse click

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

So I have a listbox that is bound to an observable collection and a property that holds index. I have an  option to delete the selected item from the listbox. After deleting I decrement the selected index and raise property changed for all properties involved.

This is working except that the selected item is highlighted with a different more gray color until the user actually clicks another item in the listbox. So basically the highlight style is different if I change selected index programmatically as opposed to changing it as the result of user mouse click.

Anyone know how I can get the bold blue highlight for selected index from a user click to be the same bold blue highlight if the selected index is set as the result of decrementing the underlying index variable?

Comment: This is part of the template for the listbox.  You'll have to change the template if you don't like it.  It's relatively easy to do, if you can get a copy of that template, tho.

Comment: @Will: Would not recommend this, this would fix the problem in the wrong place and create unintuitive interaction (wrong assumptions about focus).

Comment: @H.B. true, but the styling on listbox selection is kinda... weird. I've noticed this in the past.  The unfocused highlight is too damn light.

Answer (score 2):

This is a focus issue; it's greyed out if the `ListBox` itself is not focused. This serves the purpose of letting you know that e.g. hitting down will not select the item below the selected item, as the focus is currently elsewhere.

You will want to focus (or keyboard focus, couldn't tell you right now) the `ListBox` after the deletion process, make sure not to break MVVM of course.